# Mysql returns only one row when using Count

Tags: mysql, count, limit

Well I've just hit a weird behaviour that I've never seen before, or haven't noticed.

I'm using this query:

```
  SELECT *, 
         COUNT(*) AS pages 
    FROM notis 
   WHERE cid = 20 
ORDER BY nid DESC 
   LIMIT 0, 3
```

...to read 3 items but while doing that I want to get the total rows.

### Problem is...

...when I use count the query only returns one row, but if I remove
`COUNT(*) AS pages` -- I get the 3 rows as I'm suppose to. Obviously, i'm missing something here.

Comment: You need something like Window Functions which unfortunately are not supported by MySQL. You will have to do two separate queries.

Comment: Even then, the data doesn't belong together. What he's actually asking for is akin to "For the first three people in department 20, give me their first name and last name, and the total number of people in department 20." yeah, you can ask that, but it doesn't make sense to ask that, because you'll get the total number of people in department 20 three times.

Comment: well is it really that stupid of a question, i mean it seems to me fairly logic that you ask for total person in a department and get the information of the 3 first that "moved in"

Comment: @Breezer, then ask for that:
select count(*) from notis where cid =20; select * from notis where cid=20 limit 0,3

Comment: @Breezer you're asking for two disparate pieces of data. Ask for them seperately, don't try to combine them into a single query where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: yeah I've understood it now but i was hoping that i wouldn't need to make 2 queries agains the db

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, the count is an aggregate operator, which makes only one row returned (without a group by clause)

Maybe make two separate queries? It doesn't make sense to have the row return the data and the total number of rows, because that data doesn't belong together.

If you really really want it, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *, (select count(*) FROM notis WHERE cid=20) AS count FROM notis WHERE cid=20 ORDER BY nid DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

or this:

```
SELECT N.*, C.total from notis N join (select count(*) total FROM notis WHERE cid=20) C WHERE cid=20) AS count FROM notis WHERE cid=20 ORDER BY nid DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

With variances on the nested expression depending on your SQL dialect.

Comment: yeah this seems to be the last resort making two calls, thanks

Answer (score 14):

Using an aggregate function *without* a GROUP BY will always return one row, no matter what. You must use a GROUP BY if you want to return more than one row.

Note that on most RDBMS, such a query would have failed because it makes no sense.

Comment: but if I use group by the count function returns 1 as result

Comment: Yes, as Pablo Santa Cruz said, you would need to use a window function, but it is not supported by MySQL. You'll have to do 2 queries.

Answer (score 3):

This is inefficient, but will work:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notis WHERE cid=20) AS pages
FROM notis 
WHERE cid=20 
ORDER BY nid DESC 
LIMIT 0,3
```