# MySQL inquiry does not make difference when using order by

Tags: mysql, database

I create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    value int(20)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I insert some data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|     0 |
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
+-------+
```

When I execute `SELECT COUNT(value), value FROM my_table;` and `SELECT COUNT(value), value FROM my_table ORDER BY value DESC;`, they both show:

```
+--------------+-------+
| COUNT(value) | value |
+--------------+-------+
|            4 |     0 |
+--------------+-------+
```

My question is: why the column at the right side is always 0? Why `ORDER BY value DESC` doesn't make any difference here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql returns only one row when using Count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082713/mysql-returns-only-one-row-when-using-count)

Comment: Because it is stated in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Strictly saying, your SQL is not valid as you're using aggregate function without `GROUP BY` clause with mixing of non-group column. Server is free to select any row matching condition.

Comment: and by default the first row is selected

Comment: ^ well, that is indeed so, but I would not rely on that fact in any context as there are no references in documentation to that. More, it is even said that: `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. `

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` is processed **after** it generates the results. When you use an aggregate function like `COUNT()` without `GROUP BY`, it aggregates all the selected rows, and this produces one row of results. Any non-aggregated columns come from indeterminate rows; the `ORDER BY` clause has no effect on how this row is selected.

Comment: I do want to know, however, that the MySQL documentation uses the adjective "indeterminate" rather than "arbitrary" ;)

Answer (score -1):

ORDER BY sorts the result rows.  What you are looking for is MAX() or MIN() on the value

```
SELECT COUNT(value), MAX(value) FROM my_table;
SELECT COUNT(value), MIN(value) FROM my_table;
```