# Why does mysql query with multiple count statements returning single value?

Tags: mysql

I'm creating simple galleries, and each gallery can be mixed images/videos. In a gallery listing I wanted to display number of images/videos per each gallery. However, I'm receiving only one result row and really don't know why.

Sample galleries table:

```
id  title
=====================
1   Simple gallery
2   Test gallery
```

Simple gallery_items table:

```
id  gallery_id  type   title
================================
1   1           image  title1
2   1           image  title2
3   1           video  title3
4   1           image  title4
5   2           image  title5
6   2           image  title6
```

Query I'm using is:

```
select galleries.*, count(distinct A.id) as IMG, count(distinct B.id) as VID 
from galleries
left join gallery_items A on (galleries.id=A.gallery_id and A.type='image')
left join gallery_items B on (galleries.id=B.gallery_id and B.type='video')
```

and this is producing expected result:

```
id  title           IMG VID
================================
1   Simple gallery  3   1
```

but problem is that only one row is displaying. No way to display all rows... Any idea?

Comment: Because you don't have a group by.

Comment: group by where exactly and grouping what?

Comment: If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql returns only one row when using Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082713/mysql-returns-only-one-row-when-using-count)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Salmon was right... just adding "group by galleries.id" solves problem :)

```
select galleries.*, count(distinct A.id) as IMG, count(distinct B.id) as VID 
from galleries
left join gallery_items A on (galleries.id=A.gallery_id and A.type='image')
left join gallery_items B on (galleries.id=B.gallery_id and B.type='video')
group by galleries.id
```

Comment: `galleries.*` has a smell, although since you aggregate by `id`, presumably a primary key, it is OK.